# Remove outliers from correlation coefficient calculation

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

Assume we have two numeric vectors `x` and `y`. The Pearson correlation coefficient between `x` and `y` is given by

> cor(x, y)

How can I automatically consider only a subset of `x` and `y` in the calculation (say 90%) as to maximize the correlation coefficient?

Comment: What do you consider an outlier here? Deviation from the least squares fit line (i.e. largest residuals), or values at the the extremes of the bivariate distribution of `x` and `y`?

Comment: @Gavin Here I consider the largest residuals to be outliers.

Comment: @Gavin, any idea how to remove outliers at the extremes of the distribution? Thanks! I'm using ```hetcor``` function if imporant.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this (remove the largest (absolute) residuals), then we can employ the linear model to estimate the least squares solution and associated residuals and then select the middle n% of the data. Here is an example:

Firstly, generate some dummy data:

```
require(MASS) ## for mvrnorm()
set.seed(1)
dat <- mvrnorm(1000, mu = c(4,5), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.8,1,0.8), ncol = 2))
dat <- data.frame(dat)
names(dat) <- c("X","Y")
plot(dat)
```

Next, we fit the linear model and extract the residuals:

```
res <- resid(mod <- lm(Y ~ X, data = dat))
```

The `quantile()` function can give us the required quantiles of the residuals. You suggested retaining 90% of the data, so we want the upper and lower 0.05 quantiles:

```
res.qt <- quantile(res, probs = c(0.05,0.95))
```

Select those observations with residuals in the middle 90% of the data:

```
want <- which(res >= res.qt[1] & res <= res.qt[2])
```

We can then visualise this, with the red points being those we will retain:

```
plot(dat, type = "n")
points(dat[-want,], col = "black", pch = 21, bg = "black", cex = 0.8)
points(dat[want,], col = "red", pch = 21, bg = "red", cex = 0.8)
abline(mod, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

[image: The plot produced from the dummy data showing the selected points with the smallest residuals]

The correlations for the full data and the selected subset are:

```
> cor(dat)
          X         Y
X 1.0000000 0.8935235
Y 0.8935235 1.0000000
> cor(dat[want,])
          X         Y
X 1.0000000 0.9272109
Y 0.9272109 1.0000000
> cor(dat[-want,])
         X        Y
X 1.000000 0.739972
Y 0.739972 1.000000
```

Be aware that here we might be throwing out perfectly good data, because we just choose the 5% with largest positive residuals and 5% with the largest negative. An alternative is to select the 90% with smallest *absolute* residuals:

```
ares <- abs(res)
absres.qt <- quantile(ares, prob = c(.9))
abswant <- which(ares <= absres.qt)
## plot - virtually the same, but not quite
plot(dat, type = "n")
points(dat[-abswant,], col = "black", pch = 21, bg = "black", cex = 0.8)
points(dat[abswant,], col = "red", pch = 21, bg = "red", cex = 0.8)
abline(mod, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

With this slightly different subset, the correlation is slightly lower:

```
> cor(dat[abswant,])
          X         Y
X 1.0000000 0.9272032
Y 0.9272032 1.0000000
```

Another point is that even then we are throwing out good data. You might want to look at Cook's distance as a measure of the strength of the outliers, and discard only those values above a certain threshold Cook's distance. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook's_distance) has info on Cook's distance and proposed thresholds. The `cooks.distance()` function can be used to retrieve the values from `mod`:

```
> head(cooks.distance(mod))
           1            2            3            4            5            6 
7.738789e-04 6.056810e-04 6.375505e-04 4.338566e-04 1.163721e-05 1.740565e-03
```

and if you compute the threshold(s) suggested on Wikipedia and remove only those that exceed the threshold. For these data:

```
> any(cooks.distance(mod) > 1)
[1] FALSE
> any(cooks.distance(mod) > (4 * nrow(dat)))
[1] FALSE
```

none of the Cook's distances exceed the proposed thresholds (not surprising given the way I generated the data.)

Having said all of this, why do you want to do this? If you are just trying to get rid of data to improve a correlation or generate a significant relationship, that sounds a bit fishy and bit like data dredging to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such an excellent answer! The reason I want to do this is the following. I'm benchmarking various methods for predicting experimental observations (changes in binding energy upon mutation of a protein complex) based on experimental structures of the complexes. The target values come from various sources with varying quality. And errors in the structures can severely impact the predictions. So I have several outliers, but looking at a "pruned" correlation for various methods will allow me to more easily select the method that works best for the favorable cases.

Answer (score 20):

Using `method = "spearman"` in `cor` will be robust to contamination and is easy to implement since it only involves replacing `cor(x, y)` with `cor(x, y, method = "spearman")`.

Repeating Prasad's analysis but using Spearman correlations instead we find that the Spearman correlation is indeed robust to the contamination here, recovering the underlying zero correlation:

```
set.seed(1)

# x and y are uncorrelated
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)
cor(x,y)
## [1] 0.006401211

# add contamination -- now cor says they are highly correlated
x <- c(x, 500)
y <- c(y, 500)
cor(x, y)
## [1] 0.995741

# but with method = "spearman" contamination is removed & they are shown to be uncorrelated
cor(x, y, method = "spearman")
## [1] -0.007270813
```

Comment: `spearman` will be robust to some types of contamination, namely single high value points being perfectly correlated resulting in an inflated `pearson` correlation. It won't be completely robust to contamination by outliers at the lower end of the scale though.

Answer (score 10):

This may have been already obvious to the OP, but just to make sure... You have to be careful because trying to maxmimize correlation may actually tend to *include* outliers. (@Gavin touched on this point in his answer/comments.) I would be *first* removing outliers, *then* calculating a correlation. More generally, we want to be calculating a correlation that is robust to outliers (and there are many such methods in R).

Just to illustrate this dramatically, let's create two vectors `x` and `y` that are uncorrelated:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)
> cor(x,y)
[1] 0.006401211
```

Now let's add an outlier point `(500,500)`:

```
x <- c(x, 500)
y <- c(y, 500)
```

Now the correlation of *any* subset that includes the outlier point will be close to 100%, and the correlation of any sufficiently large subset that excludes the outlier will be close to zero.  In particular,

```
> cor(x,y)
[1] 0.995741
```

If you want to estimate a "true" correlation that is not sensitive to outliers, you might try the `robust` package:

```
require(robust)
> covRob(cbind(x,y), corr = TRUE)
Call:
covRob(data = cbind(x, y), corr = TRUE)

Robust Estimate of Correlation: 
            x           y
x  1.00000000 -0.02594260
y -0.02594260  1.00000000
```

You can play around with parameters of `covRob` to decide how to trim the data.
***UPDATE:*** There is also the `rlm` (robust linear regression) in the `MASS` package.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another possibility with the outliers captured.   Using a similar scheme as Prasad:

```
library(mvoutlier)    
set.seed(1)    
x <- rnorm(1000)    
y <- rnorm(1000)    
xy <- cbind(x, y)    
outliers <- aq.plot(xy, alpha=0.975) #The documentation/default says alpha=0.025.  I think the functions wants 0.975   
cor.plot(x, y)    
color.plot(xy)   
dd.plot(xy)   
uni.plot(xy)
```

In the other answers, 500 was stuck on the end of x and y as an outlier.   That may, or may not cause a memory problem with your machine, so I dropped it down to 4 to avoid that.

```
x1 <- c(x, 4)     
y1 <- c(y, 4)    
xy1 <- cbind(x1, y1)    
outliers1 <- aq.plot(xy1, alpha=0.975) #The documentation/default says alpha=0.025.  I think the functions wants 0.975
cor.plot(x1, y1)    
color.plot(xy1)    
dd.plot(xy1)    
uni.plot(xy1)
```

Here are the images from the x1, y1, xy1 data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I e-mailed the maintainer for mvoutlier about the problem I was having with alpha in the above aq.plot() statements. He has since fixed the problem and updated mvoutlier to version 1.6 (updated Jan 14, 2011) http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvoutlier/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You might try bootstrapping your data to find the highest correlation coefficient, e.g.:

```
x <- cars$dist
y <- cars$speed
percent <- 0.9         # given in the question above
n <- 1000              # number of resampling
boot.cor <- replicate(n, {tmp <- sample(round(length(x)*percent), replace=FALSE); cor(x[tmp], y[tmp])})
```

And after run `max(boot.cor)`. Do not be dissapointed if all the correlation coefficients will be all the same :)